# Can a non-nested query for filtering data with "LIKE" and "NOT LIKE"?

Tags: sql

We have some data starting with the same prefix in a colume of a DB table A, for example, fooABC and foobooABC. And our app has multiple profiles and there is a DB for each profile. And the rest of those data varies from a DB to another DB. I have a query for selecting a data starting with "foo" but not "fooboo".

```
select * 
from (select * 
      from A a 
      where a.field like 'foo%') a1 
where a1.field not like 'fooboo%'
```

Although it works, I am wondering whether it is a better way such as a non-nested query for the selection or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `AND` so row match both condition

```
  select * 
  from A a 
  where a.field like 'foo%'
    and a.field not like 'fooboo%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You think if you select foo% first, then the criteria for fooboo% has only to be checked on these records rather than on the whole table I guess. But is this better or not? I suggest you leave it up to the DBMS to decide for the best approach and simply ask for what data you want to see.

This is what SQL is about: tell the DBMS what you want to see, not how to do that.

```
select * 
from A 
where field like 'foo%'
and field not like 'fooboo%';
```

Thus you have a very readable query (which is easy to maintain). A good DBMS will probably come up with the same execution plan for both queries anyway.